# Azure Mobile Services update invalid id value specified

Tags: sql, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an SQL table in Azure that I'm trying to update from a scheduler script like so:

```
            var updatesTable = tables.getTable('myTable');
            var updatedRecord;              
            updatedRecord = {
                            id:1,
                            ArmastChanged: 'False'
                                         };
            updatesTable.update(updatedRecord)
```

This gives me an "invalid id value specified" error in the log when I try running it. I have one row in the table with an id of 1. I've tried putting quotations around the 1 and various other things but nothing helps. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by changing the schedule script to

```
var sql;

sql = "UPDATE [Table] SET [Field]=0 WHERE id=1";            

mssql.query(sql);
```

and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error if I made a schema change outside of the Azure portal or CLI.  I was able to resolve the issue by re-saving one of my API scripts through the portal that was using the table.  Not sure if it has to be a script that uses the table or something AMS is doing when any script is saved.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried slightly changing the script and saving it (just for the sake of re-saving) but it didn't seem to help. Can you clarify what you did? Maybe I'm missing something. Thank you so much!